# How to run single java files independently in Intellij IDEA or vscode?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, intellij-idea

I need to run single java files independently in Intellij IDEA or vscode. Currently, when I run a single program both IDEs checks for other files.

For example, in the given image, I need to run ReversingString program only, but it doesn't run it and asks me to correct error in other java files.

How can I run a single file while ignoring other files. I checked answers to other similar questions here like editing run configuration but nothing is working.

I want all files in this folder to be independent/separate from each other.

[image: Error]

***Update: I found the solution :***

**All you need to do is to basically stop building the project.**

**For that click beside the run icon - "Edit/Run configurations"  Click on modify option and check the option "Do not build before run" and now you can run a single file.**

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/16784855/12844632

Comment: @JialeDu I am trying to run only ReversingString file/class but the IDE is building/compiling all the classes in that folder. So I have to correct all the errors in other files (if any) before I can run a pacticular file which I dont want. I want to run only one class not bothering about others.

Comment: This can be fixed with [microsoft/java-debug#459](https://github.com/microsoft/java-debug/pull/459).

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

This problem has been fixed in the latest version of vscode.

---

In VS Code, you only need to click **`proceed`** in the pop-up window to compile and run the current file normally.

Below is my file structure, I open **myproject** folder in VS Code.

```
myproject
├─ DemoOne.java
└─ DemoTwo.java
```

I have two errors in **DemoTwo.java**. When I run **DemoOne.java**, a pop-up window will appear. Click **`proceed`** to compile and run demoone normally.

[image]

##### Another way:

Install the [**Code Runner**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) extension, then right-click on the **DemoOne.java** editing interface and select `Run Code`( *Ctrl + Alt + N* ). This will run the code using **Code Runner**, it will not compile all the files in the folder. Output results directly on the **OUTPUT** panel.

[image]

Comment: Yes it works in VS code. Though the problem is the same, it builds the whole project and prompts us to fix errors but we can still click Proceed and run a single file.

Comment: This problem has been fixed in the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

To run single java independently in Intellij IDEA you've choices:

- Right-click somewhere in the editing area and select Run 'ReversingString.main()'.
- Open the file in editor and use **Ctrl+Shift+F10**

read the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26467569/intellij-idea-run-debug-just-one-file) for more details.

Comment: Hi Oth. I tried both but still didn't work. It tries to build the whole project.

Comment: I suggest you to read this https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/compiling-applications.html